# How to show a sheet at a speciefic time of day?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want the sheet to be hidden all the day except a specific time.

There is a marcro like this on the net

```
Sub Auto_Open()
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00"), "HideRows"
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00"), "RevealRows"
End Sub
```

And it is about giving labels to cells

But I want it to apply to whole sheet
and be a sheet object code!

My workbook is open all the day, with a break at noon.
Im running the latest update of Microsoft Excel 2016 on Windows.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Is your Excel workbook (the .xlsx file) open all day? If yes, a VBA macro like you are asking for, can do the job. If your workbook is not open all the time, we have to talk about other options to first start your workbook at a specific time. Here, a Powershell script can be of use. Additionally it can execute/run VBA code. But before someone posts an answer, please be so kind and edit your answer and include more details about your system, my initial question and what else you've tried

Comment: @nixda Yes, it is open all the day, with a break at noon.

Comment: @nixda Updated the q

Answer (score 2):

You need to create macros which shows, then hides the sheets:

```
Sub ShowSheet()
    WorkSheets("SheetName").Visible = xlSheetVisible
End Sub

Sub HideSheet()
    WorkSheets("SheetName").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Your main sub will be:

```
Sub Auto_Run()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:00"), "ShowSheet"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:30"), "HideSheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: Where should i copy the Auto_Run() ?